# Is there an official page for ASP.NET MVC Futures?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-futures

I am planning to integrate **Mvc.Futures** in my project, but am unable to find any official documentation for this library.

Official [project page](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) on **[nuget.org](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures/5.1.0-rc1)** points to old **asp.net** project page on codeplex and even there is not so clear where information about Futures can be found.

I might be missing something, but would appreciate if anyone can give me pointers to the right place.

Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx  check this out

Comment: Only use MVC at right way, Future features are not separate things, they only enhance previews releases and no anomaly will be found. So that, You can easily update project platform each time you want!

Comment: @VishalVaishya thanks, but this is a page that explains Features, not Futures.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi My goal is to get rid of the "magic strings", and to use strongly typed Helpers for navigation. This feature was part of the Mvc.Futures from Mvc 2 and is still not part of the system.Web.Mvc library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is follow up on my own question:

I haven't found anything else related to **Mvc.Futures** after i posted this question, so i ended up using [**T4MVC**](https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) which seem to get more love from MSFT than the Futures itself (lead developer of this template is MSFT employee [David Ebbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/111888/david-ebbo)).

We are using it quite successfully so far (more than 8 months) and i am pleased with the results.

For better integration with Visual Studio i am using [AutoT4MVC](http://bennor.github.io/AutoT4MVC/) extensions which runs the T4 templates on each change in the sections of the MVC app that require rebuild (such as Controllers, Content*, Views etc..)

**To sum up** - i would suggest that you stay out of **Mvc.Futures** for now and use **T4MVC** instead.